# CoreNLP program's output not understand

Tags: nlp, parse-tree

I am new in NLP, so it may be silly question for you.
I had tried `CoreNLP` Program and got output.
There is some a question regarding to output of `CoreNLP` program.
The input sentence is "Washington voted Jorge Washington to power".
There is two tree format output.
I have a problem in second one.
There is some decimal number like `[53.180]`.
What they are referring?

1)

```
(ROOT


(S

(NP (NNP Washington))
(VP (VBD voted)
  (NP (NNP Jorge) (NNP Washington))
  (PP (TO to)
    (NP (NN power))))
(. .)))




***************************************************************************************
```

2)

```
(ROOT [53.810]

(S [53.657]

(NP [8.831] (NNP Washington))
(VP [43.691] (VBD voted)
  (NP [21.961] (NNP Jorge) (NNP Washington))
  (PP [11.075] (TO to)
    (NP [8.604] (NN power))))
(. .)))
```

Comment: May you give a code snippet providing this result ?

Comment: I think they are 'inside' probabilities (see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside_algorithm);  but you should write the code here.